# How to abort a function manually while still returning the result in Python

Tags: python, return, exit-code

In `R` it is possible to put `on.exit(return(results_so_far))` in a function, so when a user aborts the current function (in my case in Emacs), the result will still be stored.

```
def myfunc():
    on.exit(return(results))
    results = []
    for i in range(1000):
        # do something
        results.append(something)
    return(results)

res = myfunc()
```

It means that it will be possible to run some iterations and allow the function to be cancelled manually (e.g. leave a function running overnight and immediately obtain the results gathered so far in the morning).

I have looked, but I have yet to find a solution in Python. Ideas?

Comment: Play around with `globals` then?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a [`try...finally` clause](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions), as in:

```
def myfunc():
    try:
        results = []
        for i in range(1000):
            # do something
            results.append(something)
    finally:
        return(results)
```

Note that the finally clause is executed whether there is an error or interrupt or not.

Comment: I suppose it was not designed for it specifically, but it really does work well!